# How can i solve $(1+x^2)y''(x)+2xy(x)=4x^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

have come across an differential  equation
$$ (1+x^2)\frac{{d^2}y}{d{x^2}}+2xy=4x^2$$

**My approch**
:The complete solution of Ordinary linear differential equation is :

*y= complementary function + particular integral*

I have tried the method of
*undetermined coefficients* but didn't get any solution.

How can i initiate the procedure of solving. Any subtle hint is appreciated

Comment: Try power series

Comment: $y=2x$ is a solution......

Comment: @Isham, true, but we need to find the homogeneous solution as well.

Comment: true ...... Ninad

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$(1+x^2)\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}+2xy=4x^2$

$(x^2+1)\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}+2x(y-2x)=0$

Let $u=y-2x$ ,

Then $\dfrac{du}{dx}=\dfrac{dy}{dx}-2$

$\dfrac{d^2u}{dx^2}=\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}$

$\therefore(x^2+1)\dfrac{d^2u}{dx^2}+2xu=0$

Which relates to [Heun's Confluent Equation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/31.12#E1).

Comment: Rewording, I'm not sure I'm seeing how this relates to the equations linked on that page because they all have real singularities, but this one has singularities at $\pm i$. Also, this is just a rephrasing of the statement that the solution to the differential equation is the particular plus homogeneous.

Comment: I dont see how you transform this DE to Heun's equation.

Comment: So what can i consider as final solution